# Does windows 7 supports svg rendering?

Tags: windows, svg, internet-explorer-11

I am having windows 7 OS and IE11 browser. IE11 will support svg so that we have checked the condition as below

```
 var svgSupport = (window.SVGSVGElement) ? true : false;
        if (svgSupport) {
         //svgrender;
       }
        else{
         //vmlrender
       }
```

but vmlrendering is happening because window.SVGSVGElement is false. i want the svg render to take place as i am having iE11 browser. IS there any best way to detect the svg and vml? and why window.SVGSVGElement is false in windows 7?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @BigBadaboom i have another question why window.SVGSVGElement is false in windows 7? though i am using ie11 in my system

Comment: I don't know the explanation why window.SVGSVGElement works in some browsers, but not IE.